# setLocation after window moved

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, mousemove

I made a drag'n'drop algorithm to let components be dragged inside the window.

It performs well, until I move the frame window...

If I move the window, the position of the component is then shifted from a distance equal to the distance I moved the frame when I click on it and when I drag it.

Anyone knows why ?

Code sample:

```
public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {

    if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {

        origin = panel.getLocationOnScreen();

        panel.setLocation(origin.x, origin.y-panel.getHeight()/2);

        view.add(panel, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

   if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {

       panel.setLocation(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - panel.getWidth()/2, e.getLocationOnScreen().y - panel.getHeight()/2);

   }

}
```

Comment: I would expect that `e.getLocationOnScreen()` gives global coordinates, whereas `panel.setLocation(...)` uses relative coordinates. But that doesn't explain why it works in the first place...

Comment: @Heuster, you would know how to convert the setLocation to globale coordinate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the mouse events are raised by the container in which the panel should be dragged, you should use relative coordinates only.

That is, use

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
   if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
      panel.setLocation(e.getPoint().x - panel.getWidth()/2, e.getPoint().y - panel.getHeight()/2);
   }
}
```